# How to use Python to login to a webpage and retrieve cookies for later usage?

Tags: python, http, authentication, cookies

I want to download and parse webpage using python, but to access it I need a couple of cookies set. Therefore I need to login over https to the webpage first. The login moment involves sending two POST params (username, password) to /login.php. During the login request I want to retrieve the cookies from the response header and store them so I can use them in the request to download the webpage /data.php.

How would I do this in python (preferably 2.6)? If possible I only want to use builtin modules.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

username = 'myuser'
password = 'mypassword'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'j_password' : password})
opener.open('http://www.example.com/login.php', login_data)
resp = opener.open('http://www.example.com/hiddenpage.php')
print resp.read()
```

`resp.read()` is the straight html of the page you want to open, and you can use `opener` to view any page using your session cookie.

Comment: Is this safe? Won't this allow packet sniffers to see plaintext passwords? Would using Https be more secure?

Comment: @Heartinpiece Yes, if the server offers it you should use HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you...but imagin we logged in and want to post sth...how to set coockie in this thread for post data?

Comment: Highly recommend to use requests library if you are writing large code. (personal experience)

Comment: @HarleyHolcombe what would be the Python 3 equivalent to this code?

Answer (score 158):

Here's a version using the excellent [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library:

```
from requests import session

payload = {
    'action': 'login',
    'username': USERNAME,
    'password': PASSWORD
}

with session() as c:
    c.post('http://example.com/login.php', data=payload)
    response = c.get('http://example.com/protected_page.php')
    print(response.headers)
    print(response.text)
```

Comment: Is `'action': 'login'` actually necessary in this example, or is it just an extra parameter that's sent with the request?

Comment: @Ted That part is totally needed.

Comment: @Ted Maybe it is required in this particular example. It was not needed in my program.

Comment: This is the best I know of. You might have to data as per website.