# Accept Cookies in Python

Tags: python, cookies

How can I accept cookies in a python script?

Comment: Maybe you should be more specific. What are you trying to accomplish? Which framework are you using, if any?

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
import urllib2 
import cookielib

jar = cookielib.FileCookieJar("cookies")
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))

print "Currently have %d cookies" % len(jar)
print "Getting page"
response = opener.open("http://google.com")
print response.headers
print "Got page"
print "Currently have %d cookies" % len(jar)
print jar
```

It should print

```
Currently have 0 cookies
...
Currently have 2 cookies
```

(Google always sets a cookie). You don't really need this much unless you want to save your cookies to disk and use them later. You should find that

```
urllib2.build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor).open(url)
```

Takes care of most of what you want.

More info here:

- [HTTPCookieProcessor](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor)
- [build_opener](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen)
- [FileCookieJar](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html#cookielib.FileCookieJar)
- [Urllib2 - the missing maual](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml)

Answer (score 6):

**The easiest way is to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) library.**

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.google.com/doodles/'
r = requests.get(url)
print r.cookies
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: short and sweet, and worked.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at [cookielib](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean having a Python script that tries to speak HTTP.
I suggest you to use a high-level library that handles cookies automatically.
pycurl, mechanize, twill - you choose.

For Nikhil Chelliah:

I don't see what's not clear here.

**Accepting** a cookie happens client-side. The server can **set** a cookie.

Comment: A server can also get cookies from the client.  Then again, "accept" might only be a valid term for the client.

Answer (score 1):

There's the cookielib library. You can also implement your own cookie storage and policies, the cookies are found in the set-cookie header of the response (Set-Cookie: name=value), then you send the back to a server in one or more Cookie headers in the request (Cookie: name=value).

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear whether you want a client-side or a server-side solution.

For client-side, [cookielib](http://www.docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html) will work fine.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189555/how-to-use-python-to-login-to-a-webpage-and-retrieve-cookies-for-later-usage#answer-189580) and a few web tutorials offer more in-depth explanations.

If this is a server-side problem, you should be using a framework that takes care of all the boilerplate.  I really like how [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/Cookies) and [web.py](http://webpy.org/cookbook/cookies) handle them, but the API is pretty simple in any library.