# Make a list of all the files on a website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am working on a program that searches for something on the internet using `xgoogle`, then finds all the files in the websites of the results. I am having trouble with finding all the files in a website. I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786210/list-all-files-in-an-online-directory-with-python) that was similar, but I couldn't get it to work. Here is the code I've been using.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
def find_files():
    url = "http://www.python.org"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)
    for a in soup.find('div', {'class': 'catlist'}).find_all('a'):
        yield url + a['href']
```

The code doesn't run when I call it. I have put print statements in the function, but nothing happens. 
What should I do to fix it? How could this function return a list of all the files in the website?

Comment: hi, what do you mean by "files in the website"?  Are you referring to the links on the pages?

Comment: I am referring to the filesystem of the page. For example, a result from find_files("http://www.python.org") would be http://www.python.org/doc/ along with http://www.python.org/about/ and all the other directories and files that are in the site's filesystem.

Comment: Neither of those are "files" or "directories". They are links.

Comment: ok, so you're wanting to get a list of the 'href' attributes of the `<a>` tags?

Comment: Do you actually **loop** over `find_files()`? Try `for result in find_files(): print result`. This is a generator function, and it doesn't do anything until you iterate over it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this to get you started..

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def find_files():
    url = "http://www.python.org"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

    hrefs = []

    for a in soup.find_all('a'):
        hrefs.append(a['href'])

    return hrefs

list_of_links = find_files()

## show what you've found:
for link in list_of_links:
    print link
```

As you will see, you can't just add the `url` to all the results, as some of them are for other sites, so some of the resulting URLs would not exist... you should be taking a decision on all of the hits you get.

**Also, please check on sites' policies regarding webpage scraping before running this**

If you wanted to do this as a **generator**, the following might be of use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def find_files(url):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

    for a in soup.find_all('a'):
        yield a['href']

for link in find_files("http://www.python.org"):
    print link
```

note - I've moved your `url` to make this code more reusable.

Comment: woah dude, python is open-source so is the site *clean excuse*

Comment: @KDawG, yeah, but it just seems rude not to check first :)

Answer (score 1):

Appending it into a list is probably the easiest code to read, but python does support a way to get a list through iteration in just one line of code. This example should work:

```
my_list_of_files = [a['href'] for a in soup.find('div', {'class': 'catlist'}).find_all('a')]
```

This can substitute the entire for loop.

On a side note, this is also works a bit faster, but that shouldn't be a problem. This should work, assuming the data it iterates through is correct and in the correct format.