# Download and SAVE MANY Images from google Image search to a LOCAL FOLDER (Python)

Tags: python, image, url, download

The following code can download from a website one image per time. However, what I really want to achieve is to download MANY Images from a website *based on a query* and then save these images into a LOCAL FOLDER on my computer.

I am a complete beginner to programming and python. How can I achieve this?

```
import urllib.request
file = "Facts.jpg" # file to be written to
url = "http://www.compassion.com/Images/Hunger-Facts.jpg"
response = urllib.request.urlopen (url)
fh = open(file, "wb") #open the file for writing
fh.write(response.read()) # read from request while writing to file
```

Comment: Look at this other post this looks like what you want to do [HERE][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786210/list-all-files-in-an-online-directory-with-python

Comment: Thanks @Victor. I have viewed the post and it's quite related. However, I do not understand the part this part:

Comment: def download_game(url):
    # You have to do this stuff. I'm lazy and won't do it.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for game in get_all_games():
        download_game(url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a function and use that function to repeat the task for each image url that you would like to write to disk:

```
def image_request(url, file):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    fh = open(file, "wb") #open the file for writing
    fh.write(response.read()) #
```

For example, if you had a list with urls you could loop over the list:

```
for i, url in enumerate(urllist):
    image_request(url, str(i) + ".jpg")
```

Comment: A better looping construct here would be: `for i, url in enumerate(urllist):`

Comment: Thanks for the answers, Michael and Gerrat. However, your answers assume that I already have a list of urls. Is there a way I can get all files with a particular extention (e.g. JPG/PNG) within a particular website (e.g. Google Images)? Thanks.

Comment: Check out Beautiful Soup.