# How to web crawl some sites

Tags: web-crawler

I am starting a new project of crawling websites to retrieve and store data internally using a web service. I looked up some information and came across Scrapy and Beevolve web crawling services.

My question is is it best to just create my own crawler with no prior experience or rent a web crawling service?

One issue that I came across is, some of the websites require a log in before getting any data.

Comment: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Comment: I'd definitely recommend starting with Scrapy.  Even if you don't have much Python experience, it's pretty easy to use and *very* flexible.

Comment: Let's say I have no python experience. Although it comes with documentation.

Comment: I also had zero Python experience, but had no problem building a basic crawler just following the tutorials.  When I didn't understand some Python syntax, I just looked stuff up.  Luckily Python is a pretty easy language to get started with, and kinda fun.

Comment: When you say basic crawler, you mean in Scrapy? I am pretty sure it won't be rocket science but wanted to get an idea. Thanks.

Comment: Did you just ask "is it better to code it myself or pay someone for theirs"?

Comment: Correct, in Scrapy.  I also wrote a [blog post](http://blog.kitchenpc.com/2012/05/30/the-itsy-bitsy-spider-part-1/) on my experience.  Maybe it'll help you!

Comment: Wow the article is pretty neat. I gave it a 5 star, after skimming through and finding it so easy to articulate.

Comment: Did you ever write part 2 of the article? :)

Comment: [I did!](http://blog.kitchenpc.com/2012/06/08/the-itsy-bitsy-spider-part-2/)

Comment: Thanks. I tried to put a 2 in the first article and it didn't work :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create your own web crawler in Java you may want to look at [this](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)

You could also take a look at [jSpider](http://j-spider.sourceforge.net/) and [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Edit : This could work too : [crawler4j](https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/)

Comment: Maybe it's a dumb question but, will JSpider will work with other websites too?

Comment: what do you mean by "other websites" ?

Comment: I have like 25 websites which I need certain data from and crawl and save the information into my database.

Comment: I think you need to see [how it works](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/), I don't know if I answer your question but you could use asynchonous functions to crawl several websites at a time.

Comment: JSoup seems like a web site parser which most likely won't work for my need but the JSpider looks promising. Thank you for taking the time to provide the information.