# How to act like logged-in user while crawling the site?

Tags: python, authentication, web-crawler

There is a web-site to crawl, with POST-authentication.

How can I, having login and password for it, crawl closed sections of this site?

Comment: Login and remember cookies between requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This similar question here might help: [How to use Python to login to a webpage and retrieve cookies for later usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189555/how-to-use-python-to-login-to-a-webpage-and-retrieve-cookies-for-later-usage) and this too: [Python Site Login](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/278635/python-site-login) and finally this: [Login to website using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316818/login-to-website-using-python) shows how to login and use the logged in cookie for the rest of the session thus letting you parse/scrape 'closed' sections. Have a look at the [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) too for more help

Answer (score 3):

Granted you could use urllib2 to do POST authentication and do the crawling. But if you haven't already learned urllib2, you are probably much better off using the nice `requests` library.

You can find instructions and really nice tutorial at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html.

To install the package do `pip install requests`. On Mac or other Unix systems, you'll need to prefix the command with `sudo`, like this `sudo pip install requests`

Answer (score 2):

You ought to watch the recent PyCon talk by *Asheesh Laroia* titled "[*Web scraping: Reliably and efficiently pull data*](http://pyvideo.org/video/609/web-scraping-reliably-and-efficiently-pull-data)"

The lecture is 2h39m but covers lots, and is at a friendly pace. In fact, it's one of the best programming videos i've ever seen.