# Scrapy: Do form login and then work with that session

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to do the following:

1. log into a web page (in my case zendesk.com)
2. use that session to do some post requests

In fact zendesk misses some apis (create/alter macros) which I now need to simulate simulating a browser session.

So I'm not writing a spider but try to interact with the website as my script proceeds. The post requests are not known from the start but only during my script.

In the [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-userlogin) docs, there is the following example to illustrate how to use an authenticated session in Scrapy:

```
class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):
  name = 'example.com'
  start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/users/login.php']

  def parse(self, response):
    return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                formdata={'username': 'john', 'password': 'secret'},
                callback=self.after_login)]

  def after_login(self, response):
    # check login succeed before going on
    if "authentication failed" in response.body:
        self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
        return

    # continue scraping with authenticated session...
```

But it looks like this only works for scraping, but in my case I just want to "hold" the session and further work with that session.
Is there a way to achieve this with scrapy, or are there tools that better fit this task?

Comment: I don't think scrapy is the right tool for you. scrapy is for scraping, it doesn't make sense to login and "hold" it. Try to login using urllib: http://stackoverflow.com/q/189555/248296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot @wawaruk. Based on the stackoverflow post you linked that's the solution I came up with:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib, re

zendesk_subdomain = 'mysub'
zendesk_username = '...'
zendesk_password = '...'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
resp = opener.open('http://%s.zendesk.com/access/unauthenticated' % (zendesk_subdomain))
s = resp.read()
data = dict()
data['authenticity_token'] = re.findall('<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="([^"]+)"', s)[0]
data['return_to'] = 'http://%s.zendesk.com/login' % zendesk_subdomain
data['user[email]'] = zendesk_username
data['user[password]'] = zendesk_password
data['commit'] = 'Log in'
data['remember_me'] = '1'

opener.open('https://localch.zendesk.com/access/login', urllib.urlencode(data))
```

from there with opener all pages can be accessed, e.g.

```
opener.open('http://%s.zendesk.com/rules/new?filter=macro' % zendesk_subdomain)
```

Comment: mechanize can simplify your life even more: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize

Comment: I finally wrapped it all into a class and added method handling (especially needing PUT for adding zendesk macros): http://pastie.org/private/zxc7samxczqbiw29v91fg