# mechanize._mechanize.LinkNotFoundError

Tags: python, click, mechanize

I try to imitate a link click using this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import mechanize

targetPage = 'http://example.com/'
clickUrl="http://someurlinsideexample.com/" 

br = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())
br.open(targetUrl)
br.follow_link(url=clickUrl)
```

but I get this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 620, in find_link
    raise LinkNotFoundError()
mechanize._mechanize.LinkNotFoundError
```

What's wrong with my snippet and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably need a bit more info to help you better, but have you tried

```
for link in br.links():
    if link.url == clickUrl:
        br.follow_link(link)
```

or perhaps

`br.follow_link(text='theactualtextinthelink')`

of course the above wont work for images as far as i know