# read the cookies written by a certain site

Tags: python, cookies

I'm developing a client for some website,

when I use Chrome/Firefox to access the website, it writes some cookies in my local side, in addition to the Cookie field in HTTP response,

I need to extract those additional information from my local files to send a request which can be accepted by the remote server successfully

Can anyone tell me how to do it in Python?

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options. The best one seems to be to use urllib2. Take a look at [How to use Python to login to a webpage and retrieve cookies for later usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189555/how-to-use-python-to-login-to-a-webpage-and-retrieve-cookies-for-later-usage) for some excellent answers.

Here's the code from the top answer there. It's to log in, set some cookies, and access a restricted page:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

username = 'myuser'
password = 'mypassword'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'j_password' : password})
opener.open('http://www.example.com/login.php', login_data)
resp = opener.open('http://www.example.com/hiddenpage.php')
print resp.read()
```

Comment: en, it seems that this method doesn't work for my case, after I access the "public page" to gain cookies information, I print out the information in cj, it only contains the information returned back with the HTTPResponse, however, I checked that with FireBug Plugin in FireFox, there are obviously some missing values, which are the reason for my requests to be blocked

Comment: Could you share the contents of cj and what values are missing? It looks like the "public page" might be redirecting you to a intermediate page first to set cookies, as is often done. In that case, you have to visit that intermediate page too, programmatically.

Comment: the cj shows <Cookie JSESSIONID=************** for www.foo.com>, and the missing values are s_vnum s_vi