# Is it possible to use Python to read html from an open browser window?

Tags: python, html, browser

I'm trying to get some html tables from a site that is behind a login window. I have been unable to use mechanize or the default libraries to log in, due to an authorization key required for login that I cannot access through Python.

So the alternative I see is to use the webbrowser library to open the page, making use of Firefox's cookies to log in. Is there a way to get Python to read the html of this opened page?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the authentication scheme of the web site? I doubt it is so exotic that you cannot use Python to access it...

Comment: I asked about that previous, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203024/using-python-to-fill-out-an-online-form-standard-implementation-does-not-work). In short, there's a randomly generated authentication key generated on each page refresh, seen in the <form> tag. The suggestion I got there was to use regular expressions to access it, however I am having trouble understanding them, and so asked about this alternate method.

Comment: I had a similar problem a couple of days ago with a Client Authentication certificate that would be accepted if I used `curl` from the command line but not in any way through Python libraries. I ended up using `IEC` to automate Internet Explorer.