# How to use python libraries to log in to site requiring cookies

Tags: python, authentication, urllib2, mechanize, python-requests

I need log in to a site using python. This site uses cookies.
I've tried using `urllib2` and `requests` libraries and this [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189555/how-to-use-python-to-login-to-a-webpage-and-retrieve-cookies-for-later-usage).

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import cookielib
import urllib
import urllib2
import requests

auth_data = {
    'login': '+79269999999',
    'password': 'strongpassword',
    'source': 'MENU',
}
urls = {
    'home': r'https://qiwi.ru',
    'login': r'https://qiwi.ru/auth/login.action',
    'reports': r'https://qiwi.ru/report/list.action',
}
headers = {
    #'content-type': 'application/json',
    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)',
    'Referer': 'qiwi.ru',
}


def requests_foo():
    with requests.session() as c:
        c.get(urls['home'])
        request = c.post(urls['login'], data=auth_data, headers=headers)
        print request.headers['content-type']
        print request.status_code


def urllib_foo():
    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(
        urllib2.HTTPSHandler(),
        urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
        login_data = urllib.urlencode(auth_data)
        request = urllib2.Request(urls['home'], login_data, headers)
        opener.open(request)
    try:
        request = urllib2.Request(urls['login'], login_data, headers)
        resp = opener.open(request)
    except IOError, e:
        print e
    else:
        print resp.read()
```

But both functions return **HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized**

What should I do for log in on site?

**EDIT**

I tried using **mechanize**, but without success

```
def is_logged_in(html):
    return auth_data['login'] in html

def mechanize_foo():
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.open(urls['home'])
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    forms = [f for f in br.forms()]
    forms[0].action = urls['login']
    forms[0]['login'] = auth_data['login']
    forms[0]['password'] = auth_data['password']

    response = br.submit()
    print is_logged_in(response.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that browsing sites was not what requests was built for. If you want to emulate a web browser, then you will need to use a library called `mechanize`.

You *can* of continue to do this, but it will become painfully annoying after a while, because you will need to set up loads of boilterplate code.

Its the only tool I know that can do this, there are possibly others. [Here](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) is a link to the site, where you can learn how to use it in Python.

### EDIT

You *can* also use Selenium. Download it from [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Answer (score 0):

I used firefox+firebug to test login system. 
Main page is connecting to `login.action` two times.

First time it send `login`, `password` and `source` and get JSON data with some `token`.

Second time it send `login`, `password`, `source` and `loginToken` (received previously).

So connection to this server is more complicated.

If you have no experience better try Selenium or Mechanize (see Games Brainiac answer).

Comment: I know what **login.action** calling two times. I have **401 Error** when I make first call.