# Why cant I login into a website using request module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, post, python-requests

So I needed to login to a website as I need to do an action that requires logging in first.
Here's my code:

```
import requests from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

logdata = {'username': 'xxx', 'password': 'xxx'}
url = 'https://darkside-ro.com/?module=account&action=login&return_url='

with requests.Session() as s: 
    r = [s.post](https://s.post)(url, data=logdata)

html = r.text soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") 
print(soup.title.get_text())
```

it gives me the title of when you're not logged in :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Login to a website using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233421/login-to-a-website-using-python)

Comment: whats the title when you're logged in?

Comment: Please format your code to be valid Python syntax

Comment: @bertdida No, why would you flag my post as a duplicate question? It's nowhere near that one you linked. I used string correctly.

Comment: @Poojan The title should be "Darkside RO - The Rise of Skywalker

Comment: @dh762 Sorry I barely use stackoverflow, so I didn't know much about fomatting. sorry very much

Comment: @Reiden I mean if you just look at your post you can see what's visually wrong. What's this line mean? `html = r.text soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")` or this? `r = [s.post](https://s.post)(url, data=logdata)` it's obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm not sure why did I flagged this as duplicate, sorry.*

---

Okay, so I created a dummy account and tried logging in - I noticed that when I submit the form, the following data are sent to `https://darkside-ro.com/?module=account&action=login&return_url=`.

[image]

So to fix your issue, you have to include a `server` in your `logdata` dictionary.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

logdata = {
  'username': 'abc123456',
  'password': 'abc123456',
  'server': 'Darkside RO'
}

url = 'https://darkside-ro.com/?module=account&action=login&return_url='
with requests.Session() as s: 
    r = s.post(url, data=logdata)

html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser') 
print(soup.title.get_text())
```

Running the code above will print

```
Darkside RO - The Rise of Skywalker
```

PS: When you do this things again, it would be a good idea to check for hidden inputs in the form by inspecting the elements. On the site above, it has

```html
<input type="hidden" name="server" value="Darkside RO">
```