# Scrape Udacity website using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to be able to get a list of all the courses that i have registered for in Udacity.com. Is there a way that I can write a POST request in python to login to my account and then go to my dashboard in udacity and get a list of all the courses that I am taking ?

Comment: What have you tried? Or even Googled?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the answer to this question, I think it can help you out.  [How to use Python to login to a webpage and retrieve cookies for later usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189555/how-to-use-python-to-login-to-a-webpage-and-retrieve-cookies-for-later-usage#189580).

You can also see the udacity API documentation. https://s3.amazonaws.com/content.udacity-data.com/techdocs/UdacityCourseCatalogAPIDocumentation-v0.pdf

I am sure you can write a few lines of code to scrape the data you need using the information from the above two links