# How to get cookies of a website using python

Tags: python, cookies, web

How can I get cookies of a website from browser using python? The code currently being used is:

```
get_title = lambda html: re.findall('<title>(.*?)</title>', html, flags=re.DOTALL)[0].strip()
url = config.base_url
public_html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
print get_title(public_html)
cj = browsercookie.firefox()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_html = opener.open(url).read()
print get_title(login_html)
```

This code comes after the application has logged in. 
config.base_url = "https://10.194.13.71"
It is giving this error :  c**  File "/root/Desktop/mysonicwallnew/testservice.py", line 26, in test_service
    public_html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

**CertificateError: hostname '10.194.31.71' doesn't match either of 'www.abc.com', 'abc.com'**
**
How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you try `cookielib`? Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/189580/4350834

Comment: @Prabhakar : Please find the edited question

Comment: If you just want to read cookies you shall try 
`r = requests.get(url)
url = 'https://example.com/login'

print r.cookies`

Comment: @Prabhakar : I tried doing this. It gave this error : **File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1237, in set_tlsext_host_name
    _lib.SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(self._ssl, name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_set_tlsext_host_name'
**

Comment: where url = "https://10.194.31.71"

Comment: Can you please post full Traceback?

Comment: Link for the full traceback : https://justpaste.it/10vq2

Answer (score 0):

This works for me -

```
import requests
import browsercookie
import re

cj = browsercookie.chrome()
r = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com', cookies=cj)

get_title = lambda html: re.findall('<title>(.*?)</title>', html, flags=re.DOTALL)[0].strip()
print r.content
print get_title(r.content)
```

Try updating question with the error you are facing or the exact thing you are looking for from the cookie to get more specific answers.

Comment: The browser I am running it on is firefox..I am actually running a testcase on selenium webdriver..so in middle of the testcase I have to check whether the person is logged in or not..

Comment: I changed the code to cj = browsercookie.firefox() and got this error : **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/mysonicwallnew/testservice.py", line 24, in test_service
    cj = browsercookie.firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/browsercookie/__init__.py", line 207, in firefox
    return Firefox(cookie_file).load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/browsercookie/__init__.py", line 167, in load
    cur.execute('select host, path, isSecure, expiry, name, value from moz_cookies')
DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database
**