# How to login a site using Python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to write a code in python 3.7 that login a site.
For example, When I get username and password, the code should do the login process to the site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Python to login to a webpage and retrieve cookies for later usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189555/how-to-use-python-to-login-to-a-webpage-and-retrieve-cookies-for-later-usage)

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure of what you mean, if you're logging into a site or trying to process a login request, but I'm going to assume the former.

There's one way using Selenium. You can inspect element the site to find the id's for the input for username/password, then use the driver to send the information to those inputs.

Example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

username = "SITE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME"
password = "SITE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("path-to-driver")
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")

username_box = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
username_box.send_keys(username)

password_box = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
password_box.send_keys(password)

try:
    login_button = driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_8")
    login_button.submit()
except Exception as e:
    login_button = driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_2")
    login_button.submit()
```

This logs into facebook using the chromedriver.